# Group By ID and COUNT By SUB UNIQUE ID in Google Sheet or Excel

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting, google-sheets-query

I have this Data in Google Sheets (Most likely same principle in Excel)

```
ID     SUB ID    COUNT Unique Sub-ID

1       1A         2
1       1A         2 
1       1B         2
2       2A         1
3       3A         3
3       3B         3
3       3B         3
3       3D         3
```

So by example, the ID 1 have 1A and 1B, two unique sub ID. How can i count this way in Google sheets?

Comment: Your formula technically works in Google Sheets, but it returns 0. What exactly do you want to do? Count all the unique combinations of column A and B?

Comment: No its not working. I want to know  EX: the number of UNIQUE SUB ID for the Group ID 1

Comment: And i cant do Pivot Table since I have to many IDs.

Comment: Can't you just use simply `=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,A:A=A2)))`

Comment: Or `=COUNTUNIQUE(query(A1:B, "select B where A = 1"))`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes to easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this if you wanted to use an Array Formula:

```
=ArrayFormula({unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),countif(index(unique(A2:B),0,1),unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")))})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, QUERY(UNIQUE(A1:B), 
 "select Col1,count(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]